# jQuery validation add and remove html on success or failure

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for validation of my form and parts of the Bootstrap framework for CSS.

Now on a error, I want to show a text after the input and add a `<span class="error">` element after the input.

On succes, I want to remove the message text and add a `<span class="succes">` element after the input.

So the basic HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="myform">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="name">Name *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
  </div>
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
      var i, elements;
      for(i = 0; errorList[i]; i++) {
        errorList[i].message = errorList[i].message + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove has-error form-control-feedback'></span>"
      }
      this.defaultShowErrors()
    },
});
```

Now when the user enters a wrong input, the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <label for="name">Name *</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control error" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
  <label for="name" class="error">
    This field is required
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove has-error form-control-feedback"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

All fine for now, but how do I accomplish this HTML when the user enters a good input!

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <label for="name">Name *</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control error" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok has-success form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

Note: No `<label>` with the class `error` and the `<span>` element has different classes.

Comment: It is possible to define an error Element and a function that adds the error on any elment.

validate({errorElement: "em", errorPlacement: function(error, element) { error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );});

Take a look at the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/custom-methods-demo.html)

Comment: I can add the error element, but I alse need a success element!

Comment: The element automatically receives an error and success class.

Comment: You can also change the classname for success and error by setting the options "errorClass" and "validClass".

Comment: See the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions.

Comment: @Sparky, this indeed did the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this with the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions. See my code below.

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).nextAll('.glyphicon').removeClass('hidden');
  $(element).nextAll('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
  $(element).nextAll('.glyphicon').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).nextAll('.glyphicon').removeClass('hidden');
  $(element).nextAll('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
  $(element).nextAll('.glyphicon').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
},
```

Comment: One tip:  You don't need multiple lines since you can put more than one class inside of `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()`.  Example: `$(element).nextAll('.glyphicon').removeClass('hidden glyphicon-ok has-success').addClass('glyphicon-remove has-error');`